# Form value not return in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have upload my JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remain_credit").click("calculate_remain_credit");
});

function calculate_remain_credit() {
    var hour_start = document.getElementById(parseInt('credit_taken'));
    var hour_end = document.getElementById(parseInt('course_credit'));
    var hour_total = credit_taken - course_credit;

    document.getElementById('remain_credit').innerHTML = remain_credit;
}
```

And I am uploading also my Laravel form here:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('credit',' Remain Credit ')}}
    {!! Form::number('remain_credit', null, array('id'=>'remain_credit','placeholder' => ' Remain Credit  ','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: when I subtract credit_taken value  form course_credit value data note return.

Answer (score 3):

You should fix three problems in your code :

1. The click event attachment should look like :

   ```
   $("#remain_credit").click(calculate_remain_credit);
   ```

   Removing the quotes :

   ```
   $("#remain_credit").click("calculate_remain_credit");
   __________________________^_______________________^
   ```
2. You need to replace `innerHTML` by `value` if you want to update the input value, should be :

   ```
   document.getElementById('remain_credit').value = remain_credit;
   ```
3. You've to parse after getting the value so :

   ```
   var hour_start = document.getElementById(parseInt('credit_taken'));
   var hour_end   = document.getElementById(parseInt('course_credit'));
   ```

   Should be instead like :

   ```
   var hour_start = parseInt( document.getElementById('credit_taken').value );
   var hour_end   = parseInt( document.getElementById('course_credit').value );
   ```

The full updated code will be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remain_credit").click(calculate_remain_credit);
});

function calculate_remain_credit() {
    var hour_start = parseInt( document.getElementById('credit_taken').value );
    var hour_end   = parseInt( document.getElementById('course_credit').value );
    var hour_total = credit_taken - course_credit;

    document.getElementById('remain_credit').value = remain_credit;
}
```

Comment: @KaziBablu check the update. You should have extracted the values from `credit_taken` and `course_credit` before parsing to Int

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` should be first and then `document.getElementById`:

```
$("#remain_credit").click(calculate_remain_credit);

function calculate_remain_credit() {
    // here use parseInt before getElementById
    var hour_start = parseInt(document.getElementById('credit_taken').value);
    var hour_end = parseInt(document.getElementById('course_credit').value);
    var hour_total = credit_taken - course_credit;

    document.getElementById('remain_credit').value = hour_total;
}
```

Comment: Change the `.innerHtml` to `.value`

Comment: You need to use .value for hour_start